# Inserting data from a textfile into a new selected column in Datagridivew

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Thanks for your help in advance. Right now I'm trying to take data that I have in a text file and exporting this into datagridview. I can successfully do this once in my first two columns. Now I want to take another text file with the same data format and insert the data into the next two columns, instead of directly below my first text file data.

Here's my example text file:

Float2

> ```
> 2015/07/08 23:42:58.008,3.228
> 2015/07/08 23:42:59.008,3.198
> 2015/07/08 23:43:00.008,3.142
> 2015/07/08 23:43:01.008,3.137
> 2015/07/08 23:43:02.008,3.212
> 2015/07/08 23:43:03.008,3.216...
> ```

I can split this text file at my comma so that I have two columns of data. This is my code thus far for bringing in my data to datagridview.

```
Private Sub BtnExpDGV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExpDGV.Click
    Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader('Text File') 
    Dim rowvalue As String  
    Dim cellvalue(50) As String  

    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1   
        rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()  
        cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)  
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellvalue) 
    End While 

End Sub
```

Thanks again for the input.

Comment: You could do it concurrently (both at the same time)

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to vb.net, how would you concurrently bring in multiple text files at the same time?

Comment: Open 2 streams on the 2 files, then read items 1 and 2 from stream 1, items 3 and 4 from stream 2, then add them to the DGV